# Boost beast service returns "body limit exceeded" when receiving a json payload

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm working on a project which implement a boost beast service.This part of code was written by a person who left the company and I do not master boot.
Until now it worked well but the size of the payload has increased and it no longer works. The payload is about 2.4MB.

The service is implemented using 3 classes ServerService, Listener and Session.

**ServerService:**

```
void ServerService::startServer(const std::string& address, const unsigned short& port,
                                 const std::string& baseRessourceName, const unsigned short& threadNumber)
{
    try
    {
        const auto srvAddress = boost::asio::ip::make_address(address);

        // The io_context is required for all I/O
        auto const nbThreads = std::max<int>(1, threadNumber);
        boost::asio::io_context ioContext(nbThreads);

        // Create listener and launch a listening port
        std::shared_ptr<Listener> listener = std::make_shared<Listener>(ioContext, tcp::endpoint{ srvAddress, port }, baseRessourceName);
        listener->run();

        // Run the I/O service on the requested number of threads
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        threads.reserve(nbThreads - 1);
        for (auto i = nbThreads - 1; i > 0; --i)
        {
            threads.emplace_back([&ioContext] { ioContext.run(); });
        }
        ioContext.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
        LBC_ERROR("{}", e.what());
    }
}
```

**Listener:**

```
// Used namespace
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>


namespace Http
{
    class Listener : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Listener>
    {
    private:
        tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
        tcp::socket m_socket;
        std::string const& m_baseResourceName;

        // Report a failure
        void logError(boost::system::error_code errorCode, char const* what)
        {
            LBC_ERROR("{}: {}", what, errorCode.message());
        }

    public:
        Listener(boost::asio::io_context& ioContext, tcp::endpoint endpoint, std::string const& docRoot)
            : m_acceptor(ioContext)
            , m_socket(ioContext)
            , m_baseResourceName(docRoot)
        {
            boost::system::error_code errorCode;

            // Open the acceptor
            m_acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol(), errorCode);
            if (errorCode)
            {
                logError(errorCode, "open");
                return;
            }

            // Allow address reuse
            m_acceptor.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true));
            if (errorCode)
            {
                logError(errorCode, "set_option");
                return;
            }

            // Bind to the server address
            m_acceptor.bind(endpoint, errorCode);
            if (errorCode)
            {
                logError(errorCode, "bind");
                return;
            }

            // Start listening for connections
            m_acceptor.listen(boost::asio::socket_base::max_listen_connections, errorCode);
            if (errorCode)
            {
                logError(errorCode, "listen");
                return;
            }
        }

        // Start accepting incoming connections
        void run()
        {
            if (!m_acceptor.is_open()) {
                return;
            }
            doAccept();
        }

        void doAccept()
        {
            m_acceptor.async_accept(m_socket,
                std::bind(
                    &Listener::onAccept,
                    shared_from_this(),
                    std::placeholders::_1));
        }

        void onAccept(boost::system::error_code errorCode)
        {
            if (errorCode)
            {
                logError(errorCode, "accept");
            }
            else
            {
                // Create the session and run it
                std::make_shared<Session>(
                    std::move(m_socket),
                    m_baseResourceName)->run();
            }

            // Accept another connection
            doAccept();
        }
    };
} // namespace Http
```

**Session:**

```
// Used namespaces
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;           // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
namespace boostHttp = boost::beast::http;   // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>


namespace Http
{
    class Session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session>
    {
    private:
        // This is the C++11 equivalent of a generic lambda.
        // The function object is used to send an HTTP message.
        struct send_lambda
        {
            Session& self_;

            explicit send_lambda(Session& self) : self_(self) {}

            template<bool isRequest, class Body, class Fields>
            void operator()(boostHttp::message<isRequest, Body, Fields>&& msg) const
            {
                // The lifetime of the message has to extend
                // for the duration of the async operation so
                // we use a shared_ptr to manage it.
                auto sp = std::make_shared<boostHttp::message<isRequest, Body, Fields>>(std::move(msg));

                // Store a type-erased version of the shared
                // pointer in the class to keep it alive.
                self_.res_ = sp;

                // Write the response
                boostHttp::async_write(self_.socket_, *sp,
                    boost::asio::bind_executor(
                        self_.strand_, std::bind(
                            &Session::onWrite,
                            self_.shared_from_this(),
                            std::placeholders::_1,
                            std::placeholders::_2,
                            sp->need_eof())));
            }
        };

        // Report a failure
        void logError(boost::system::error_code errorCode, char const* what)
        {
            LBC_ERROR("{}: {}", what, errorCode.message());
        }

        tcp::socket socket_;
        boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::any_io_executor> strand_;
        boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer_;
        std::string const& baseResourceName_;
        boostHttp::request<boostHttp::string_body> req_;
        std::shared_ptr<void> res_;
        send_lambda lambda_;

    public:
        // Take ownership of the socket
        explicit Session(tcp::socket socket, std::string const& docRoot)
            : socket_(std::move(socket))
            , strand_(socket_.get_executor())
            , baseResourceName_(docRoot)
            , lambda_(*this)
        {}

        // Start the asynchronous operation
        void run()
        {
            doRead();
        }

        void doRead()
        {
            // Make the request empty before reading,
            // otherwise the operation behavior is undefined.
            req_ = {};

            // Read a request
            boostHttp::async_read(socket_, buffer_, req_,
                boost::asio::bind_executor(
                    strand_, std::bind(
                        &Session::onRead,
                        shared_from_this(),
                        std::placeholders::_1,
                        std::placeholders::_2)));
        }

        void onRead(boost::system::error_code errorCode, std::size_t transferredBytes)
        {
            boost::ignore_unused(transferredBytes);

            // This means they closed the connection
            if (errorCode == boostHttp::error::end_of_stream)
            {
                return doClose();
            }

            if (errorCode) {
                return logError(errorCode, "*** read");  // Error is here
            }

            // Some stuff here to manage request

        }

        void onWrite(boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t transferredBytes, bool close)
        {
            boost::ignore_unused(transferredBytes);

            if (ec)
            {
                return logError(ec, "write");
            }

            if (close)
            {
                // This means we should close the connection, usually because
                // the response indicated the "Connection: close" semantic.
                return doClose();
            }

            // We're done with the response so delete it
            res_ = nullptr;

            // Read another request
            doRead();
        }

        void doClose()
        {
            // Send a TCP shutdown
            boost::system::error_code ec;
            socket_.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_send, ec);

            // At this point the connection is closed gracefully
        }
    };
} // namespace Http
```

The service is launched as follow:

```
Service::ServerService serverService;
serverService.startServer("127.0.0.1", 8080, "service_name", 5);
```

I saw in the boost documentation that the default limit is 1MB. I tried some examples found on the internet to implement a parser and change the body limit but when I send a payload I get the following error "Unknown HTTP request" !
I hope someone can help me solve this problem. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I made your code self-contained, more modern, simpler and stripped unused code. I chose `libfmt` to implement the logging requirements, showing how to use source location instead of tediously providing manual context.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9686fe2af721718e)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http  = beast::http;
namespace net   = boost::asio;
using boost::system::error_code;
using net::ip::tcp;

#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>
template <> struct fmt::formatter<boost::source_location> : fmt::ostream_formatter {};
#define LBC_ERROR(FMTSTR, ...) fmt::print(stderr, FMTSTR "\n", __VA_ARGS__)

// Report a failure
static void inline logError(error_code ec, char const* what) {
    LBC_ERROR("{}: {} from {}", what, ec.message(), ec.location());
}
static void inline logError(std::exception const& e) { logError({}, e.what()); }

namespace Http {
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    using Executor = net::any_io_executor;

    class Session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
      private:
        tcp::socket                       socket_;
        std::string                       baseResourceName_; // TODO FIXME unused
        boost::beast::flat_buffer         buffer_;
        http::request<http::string_body>  req_;

      public:
        // Take ownership of the socket
        explicit Session(tcp::socket socket, std::string docRoot)
            : socket_(std::move(socket))
            , baseResourceName_(std::move(docRoot)) {}

        void run() {
            std::cerr << "Started session for " << socket_.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
            doRead();
        }

        ~Session() {
            error_code ec;
            auto ep = socket_.remote_endpoint(ec);
            std::cerr << "Close session for " << ep << std::endl;
        }

      private:
        void doRead() {
            // Make the request empty before reading, otherwise the operation
            // behavior is undefined.
            req_.clear();

            // Read a request
            http::async_read(socket_, buffer_, req_,
                             std::bind(&Session::onRead, shared_from_this(), _1, _2));
        }

        void onRead(error_code ec, size_t transferredBytes) {
            boost::ignore_unused(transferredBytes);

            // This means they closed the connection
            if (ec == http::error::end_of_stream) {
                return doClose();
            }

            if (ec) {
                return logError(ec, "*** read"); // Error is here
            }

            // Some stuff here to manage request
        }

        void onWrite(error_code ec, size_t transferredBytes, bool close) {
            boost::ignore_unused(transferredBytes);

            if (ec) {
                return logError(ec, "write");
            }

            if (close) {
                // This means we should close the connection, usually because
                // the response indicated the "Connection: close" semantic.
                return doClose();
            }

            // Read another request
            doRead();
        }

        void doClose() {
            // Send a TCP shutdown
            error_code ec;
            socket_.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_send, ec);
            // At this point the connection is closed gracefully
        }
    };
} // namespace Http

namespace Http {
    class Listener : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Listener> {
      private:
        tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
        std::string   m_baseResourceName;


      public:
        Listener(Executor ex, tcp::endpoint endpoint, std::string docRoot) try
            : m_acceptor(ex)
            , m_baseResourceName(std::move(docRoot)) //
        {
            m_acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
            m_acceptor.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
            m_acceptor.bind(endpoint);
            m_acceptor.listen(tcp::socket::max_listen_connections);
        } catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
            logError(se.code(), "Listener");
            throw;
        }

        // Start accepting incoming connections
        void run() {
            if (m_acceptor.is_open())
                doAccept();
        }

        void doAccept() {
            m_acceptor.async_accept(make_strand(m_acceptor.get_executor()),
                                    std::bind(&Listener::onAccept, shared_from_this(), _1, _2));
        }

        void onAccept(error_code ec, tcp::socket sock) {
            if (ec)
                return logError(ec, "accept");

            // Accept another connection / Create the session and run it
            doAccept();
            std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(sock), m_baseResourceName)->run();
        }
    };

    void startServer(std::string address, uint16_t port, std::string docRoot, unsigned threads) {
        try {
            net::thread_pool ioc(std::max(1u, threads));

            // Create listener and launch a listening port
            tcp::endpoint ep{net::ip::make_address(address), port};
            std::make_shared<Listener>( //
                ioc.get_executor(), ep, std::move(docRoot))
                ->run();

            // Run the I/O service on the requested number of threads
            ioc.join();
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            logError(e);
        }
    }

} // namespace Http

int main() {
    //Service::ServerService serverService;
    /*serverService.*/ Http::startServer("127.0.0.1", 8989, "service_name", 5);
}
```

> Particularly the `send_lambda` is not outdated (besides being unused), see [`message_generator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__http__message_generator.html) instead

### Reproducing

I can reproduce the error by replacing the data with something large enough:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63240c0742162fa5)**

```
dd of=test.bin seek=3 bs=1M count=0 status=none
curl -s http://127.0.0.1:8989/blrub -d @test.bin
```

Prints

```
Started session for 127.0.0.1:48884
*** read: body limit exceeded from (unknown source location)
Close session for 127.0.0.1:48884
```

### Fixing

Indeed, you can set options on `request_parser`. Three lines of code changed:

```
http::request_parser<http::string_body> req_;
```

And

```
req_.get().clear();
req_.body_limit(8*1024*1024); // raised to 8Mb
```

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37369fa2ebf4ba62)**

With no further changes: [image]

Prints

```
Started session for 127.0.0.1:48886
Close session for 127.0.0.1:48886
```

Comment: Thank you so much sehe, I try  this right now !

Comment: Any success? It's been a while, perhaps you forgot :)

Comment: Yes sorry, so busy that I forgot to close my post. It worked fine thanks again :-)